# Got operation not permitted while running flutter pub get in jenkins shell

Tags: jenkins, flutter

I placed the flutter folder under the ~/Documents folder. When I try to execute flutter relevant commands got operation not permitted.

/user/username/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: Operation not permitted.